# Iteratively rbind 10% of the data from data frame and plotting

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rbind

I have three data frames, each having 1 column but having different number of rows 100,100,1000 for df1,df2,df3 respectively. I want to do an rbind iteratively and calculate measures like mean repeatedly for the small chunks of data by taking 10% of the data each time. Meaning in the first iteration I need to have 10 rows from df1, 10 from df2 and 100 from df3 and for this set i need to get a mean and the process should continue 10 times. And I need to plot the iterations chunks over time showing the mean in y-axis over iterations and get an overall mean with this procedure. Any suggestions?

```
df1<- data.frame(A=c(1:100))
df2<- data.frame(A=c(1:100))
df3<- data.frame(A=c(1:1000))

library(dplyr)
for i in (1:10)
     { df[i]<- rbind_list(df1,df2,df3)
      mean=mean(df$A)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making things complicated by trying to keep separate data frames. Add a "group" column---call it "iteration" if you prefer---and get your data in one data frame:

```
df1$group = rep(1:10, each = nrow(df1) / 10)
df2$group = rep(1:10, each = nrow(df2) / 10)
df3$group = rep(1:10, each = nrow(df3) / 10)
df = rbind(df1, df2, df3)

means = group_by(df, group) %>% summarize(means = mean(A))
means
#  Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
#
#     group means
#  1      1    43
#  2      2   128
#  3      3   213
#  4      4   298
#  5      5   383
#  6      6   468
#  7      7   553
#  8      8   638
#  9      9   723
# 10     10   808
```

Your overall mean is `mean(df$A)`. You can plot with `with(means, plot(group, means))`.

#### Edits:

If the groups don't come out exactly, here's how I'd assign the group column. Make sure your `dplyr` is up-to-date, this uses the the `.id` argument of `bind_rows()` which was new this month in version 0.4.3.

```
library(dplyr)
# dplyr > 0.4.3

df = bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "id")
df = df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(group = (0:(n() - 1)) %/% (n() / 10) + 1)
```

The `id` column tells you which data frame the row came from, and the `group` column splits it into 10 groups. The rest of the code from above should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I had odd numbers so somehow it is not able to group them. Any ideas?